# Using es6 on mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I'm trying to incorporate es6 in my server side code. Using babel-node works when running the server , however i'm having trouble compiling es6 to es5 code when running mocha tests.

This is my folder structure

I have a server.js which starts up a worker.js file(which has the express server)

the server.js file

```
import {SocketCluster} from 'socketcluster';

const socketCluster = new SocketCluster({
  workers:1,
  brokers:1,
  port: 3000,
  appName:null,
  workerController: __dirname + '/worker.js',
  brokerController: __dirname + '/broker.js',
  socketChannelLimit: 1000,
  crashWorkerOnError: true
})
```

the worker.js file

```
export const run = (worker) => {
  console.log(' >> worker PID: ',process.pid);

  const app = express();

  const httpServer = worker.httpServer;
  const scServer = worker.scServer;

  app.use(cookieParser())

  httpServer.on('request', app);

  app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    console.log('recieved')
    res.send('Hello world')
  })

}
```

When running the server manually , it works with the below script

```
"start": "nodemon server/server.js --exec babel-node"
```

however , when i try running the test file with mocha i get an 'unexpected token "export" error'

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export const run = (broker) => {
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:511:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at initBrokerServer (/home/avernus/Desktop/projects/node-sc-react/node_modules/sc-broker/server.js:178:25)
    at process.<anonymous> (/home/avernus/Desktop/projects/node-sc-react/node_modules/sc-broker/server.js:498:9)
```

this is the script to start the mocha tests

```
"test": "mocha test/server/*.js --compilers js:babel-register"
```

am i missing something else?

this is the test file

```
import server from '../../server/server';
import http from 'http';
import assert from 'assert';
import {expect} from 'chai';

describe('Express server',() =>{
  it('should return "Hello World"',() => {
    http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000',(res) => {
      expect(res).to.contain('wtf world')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out i need to specify an `initController` in my server.js file to ensure that all files are compiled by babel. This is a problem specific to the websocket framework i'm using.

Answer (score 3):

You need to transpile test scripts from `ES2015` to `ES5` using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)  before passing it to mocha to run the tests. You can do it as follows adding/editing test script in `package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
},
...
```

**Update:**

Mocha deprecated the `--compiler` flag. Please check [**this page**](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation) for more information. The new npm script should look like below

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --require babel-register --recursive"
},
...
```

Comment: still getting the error :( .. adding --recursive doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Kunkka I am little surprised. I am using it and it just works. please check [this package.json](https://github.com/nmrony/hlsdownloader/blob/master/package.json) package

Comment: since npm start seems to work with the same source .. where else do you think i might be wrong? i think babel isnt properly compiling further imports

Comment: The problem could be that server.js requires a path to worker.js file as opposed to 'requiring' the module. so perhaps babel-register doesnt track it. but that would mean npm start shouldnt work either right?

Comment: @Kunkka please add .babelrc as project https://github.com/nmrony/hlsdownloader/blob/master/.babelrc has it